# TypeScript : What is the right way to define types

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, typescript-typings

I'm a little confused with the assignment of typescript types.
In my example I want to know how I define the type of **props** that will not be "any type" and also how I define the type of the **title, handleOnPress, svg** parameters of the `SideMenuItem` function

```
const SideMenu = (props: any) => {
  const SideMenuItem = ({ title, handleOnPress, svg }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sideMenuItem} onPress={handleOnPress}>
      <View style={styles.syncView}>
        {svg}
        <Text style={styles.sideMenuItemText}>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
```

Comment: `({ title, handleOnPress, svg }: SideMenuItemProps) => ...`

Comment: after i did it so the SideMenuItemProps is red..
its says " Cannot find name 'SideMenuItemProps ts(2304) "

Comment: can you please show me how to do it coz i am new with typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the prop types for your component in an interface

```ts
interface SideMenuItemProps {
  title: string;
  handleOnPress: () => void;
  svg: ReactNode;
}
```

Then define the prop type in the component definition

```ts
const SideMenuItem = ({ title, handleOnPress, svg }: SideMenuItemProps) => (
  //...
);
```

Comment: i have few svg that i use there ..
import SyncSVG from '~/assets/sync.svg';
import ExclamationMarkSVG from '~/assets/exclamationMark.svg';
import SyncReportSVG from '~/assets/syncReport.svg';

the SVG is red now..
it says : 
type SVG = /*unresolved*/ any
Cannot find name 'SVG'.ts(2304)

Comment: I had to guess as to what it was because you didn't provide that information in your question

Comment: @emma I've change the `svg` type to `ReactNode` which should allow any type of content

Comment: but how i care the props type ?
this is how the props look like :
https://snack.expo.dev/@roei133/f28977

Comment: i have to change the any type of the props ..it should not be any.
so i print out the props and give u a link to see how its look like and than u maybe know how i should fix the any type of the props.

Comment: You do it the same way. Define an interface (eg `SideMenuProps`) to represent the props you want to use in your component and then use `(props: SideMenuProps)` in the component args. FYI, I wouldn't recommend defining sub-components within their parents; move the `SideMenuItem` definition out of `SideMenu`

Comment: i confused, can u show me how to do it ?

Comment: @emma I have already shown you how to do it. I don't know what props you want to pass to your `SideMenu` component or how you intend on using them so I cannot answer any further than that